# How does an Android adapter decide what to re-render?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, sugarorm

Say I have a `List<User>`. Now I can wrap this list in an ArrayAdapter.

```
List<User> users = Users.getAll();
ArrayAdapter<User> = new ArrayAdapter<User>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, users);
```

I then bind the adapter to a listview to display the list of Users.

`Users.getAll()` uses Sugar ORM to query the database and return a list of users. Items can be added to the user list from the activity that displays the user list. I am wondering how do I keep the listview updated.

**Option 1**

One way is to manually update the `users` as a I add to the database and then call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`. This works, but it doesn't feel right because I am maintaining a "fake" list that represents what is in the database.

**Option 2**

I am wondering how bad is it if I just clear the items in `users`, update it with the results of a new database query and then call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`?

Will all the child views be thrown away and be re-rendered? Or does it call the `equals()` method to see if the models bound to each child is the same and then update only what is new?

**Other Info**

Since I am using SugarORM, I don't think I can get access to the Cursor to do something more efficient. However if there is a better way to keep the list synced with SugarORM, I am happy to hear that as well.

Answer (score 0):

In answer to your option 2: No, it doesnt call equals, because the adapter works in conjunction with the widget to re-use the views, it doens't create a new view foreach item in the list, it create a view foreach visible item and as you scroll re-uses view that left the screen.

The best option here is to create your own adapter, creating a class extending BaseAdapter and creating your own logic inside it requerying the database and notifying the change to the listview (or gridview)..

On the other hand doing what you said here:

I am wondering how bad is it if I just clear the items in users, update it with the results of a new database query and then call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()?

isn't bad either.

Comment: If this was the answer you were looking for please mark it as answered with the checkmark on the left

Answer (score 0):

Create a DAO class that extends `Observable`, then have your Adapter implement `Observer`. Now every time you add or remove a SugarRecord, do through the DAO class and whoever is register as the Observer will get notified through the following method:

```
@Override
public void update(Observable observable, Object o)
```

You can more about Observable/Observer pattern [here](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077258/learn-java/observer-and-observable.html). This is just one of the many examples and tutorials out there.